# MSXML 6 Service Pack (KB954459) Setup Interrupted

Tags: installation, msxml-6, msxml

Somehow, the installation of MSXML 6 got corrupted.

I'm tried to uninstall it, but the installer closes without any response.

I tried then to reinstall it, and I the [installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=59914795-60c7-4ebe-828d-f28cb457e6e3&displaylang=en) gives me this message: `MSXML 6 Service Pack (KB954459) Setup Interrupted`.

Then, I used [Windows Installer CleanUp Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301) to remove MSXML 6 from my installed programs. After this, I tried to run the installer again, but the message has not changed.

I found an equivalent question on [expert-exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Security/Misc/Q_23916489.html), but I can't see the responses.

I'm googling it for some time now, and I'm getting increasingly frustrated. Does anyone has experienced this problem? Or better, does anyone knows a solution?

I'm running an updated Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.090206-1234) on a Dell Latitude D630.

By the way, I'm not sure if this is the best site to ask this. Maybe stackoverflow.com would be better, but it's not a strictly programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was to quick to make the question here. I've just found a working solution on this eggheadcafe [thread](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=33774318&threadid=33664744). At least I hope this helps someone in the future.

Quoting the solution:

> All it took was:
>
> 1) removing the existing MSXML 6 file
>   (which cannot be done via add/remove)
>   ... you must use this Windows cleanup
>   installer:
>
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/9/d/e9d80355-7ab4-45b8-80e8-983a48d5e1bd/msicuu2.exe
>
> 2) re-installing MSXML 6 from:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=993C0BCF-3BCF-4009-BE21-27E85E1857B1&displaylang=en

Comment: I have this issue on my workstation - will running the cleanup installer remove my office installation as well?

Comment: 1. Instead of msicuu2.exe (which is not available anymore), use http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/
2. Use the exact link above, because MSXML 6.0 SP2 (msxml6-KB973686-enu-x86.exe) fails to install anyway.